# How can I write this simple SQL query?

Tags: sql, sas

It is my first post, sorry if it isn't like it should be.

I have to write this simple query.

Input table:

[image: tableinput]

Output table:

[image: outputtable]

How we can see the output table obtains the percentage of `aceptacion = 1` in the two groups (target and control).

I need the SQL query to create this output table.

Thank you.

Comment: Please review the guidelines on how to ask a question [ask] - in this case you would need to show what you've tried so far ideally. Some of this is covered in the documentation here: https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=sqlproc&docsetTarget=p0xwc73ekemkapn1byhceqrwrisb.htm&locale=en

Comment: Why not just use PROC MEANS?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `avg()`:

```
select grupo, avg(aceptacion)
from t
group by grupo;
```

Answer (score 1):

The first answer is right. Just to complement it: if you are new to sas enviroment you need to declare that you are using SQL, with `PROC SQL;`: Maybe you also need to know basic statements. So, assuming your input table is named `have` and the output table is `want`, the full code would be

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select 
grupo, 
mean(aceptacion) as aceptacion
from have
group by grupo;
```

As `aceptacion` only have two possible values (0 and 1) the mean of the variable by group will return the proportions of acceptance by group.